# Javascript Search Issue manual Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In example below, I`m copying select list option from one field to another (From id "email" to "Mail") . So if I select "Account", it will get added to text search field. This issue is with the "Search" field. Even though the value is getting copy/pasted in text search box, search is not showing any results until I manually press any key in that search box. Can someone please suggest how can I fix this issue?

I`m using filterz search model for this project which populates search results on every key pressed - http://yiotis.net/filterizr/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#email").change(function() {
    $('#mail').val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <select id="email" name="a" size="5" style="width: 400px;">
    <option value="Account">Account</option>
    <option value="Outlook">Outlook</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>

  </select>
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <input name="text" type="text" data-search="data-search" id="mail" />

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#mail').trigger("change")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually trigger `keyup` event like below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#email").change(function() {
    $('#mail').val(this.value).trigger("keyup"); // manually trigger keyup event

  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <select id="email" name="a" size="5" style="width: 400px;">
    <option value="Account">Account</option>
    <option value="Outlook">Outlook</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>

  </select>
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <input name="text" type="text" data-search="data-search" id="mail" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply call change event on #mail, just after setting value.

```js
$(function() {                                     
    $("#email").change(function() {                  
        $('#mail').val(this.value);    
      $('#mail').change();
    });
  $('#mail').change(function(){ 
    console.log("serach now");
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
      <select id="email" name="a" size="5" style="width: 400px;">
        <option value="Account">Account</option>
        <option value="Outlook">Outlook</option>
        <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>

      </select>
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
        <input name="text" type="text" data-search="data-search" id="mail" />
      
    </form>
```